# TypeError: can't concat str to bytes for google indexing API

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use Google's indexing API to push page crawl in GSC but I'm currently getting this error "TypeError: can't concat str to bytes".

**CODE:**

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2
import json
import pandas as pd

SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing"
ENDPOINT = "https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish"
JSON_KEY_FILE = "river-formula-BLABLA.json"

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(JSON_KEY_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
content = {"url":"https://www.parmalat.it/chef/ricette/cannelloni-al-ragu","type":"URL_UPDATED"}

response, content=http.request(ENDPOINT, method="POST", body=content)

print(response)
print(content)
```

**RESULT:**

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)

   1041                 if encode_chunked and self._http_vsn == 11:
   1042                     # chunked encoding
-> 1043                     chunk = f'{len(chunk):X}\r\n'.encode('ascii') + chunk \
   1044                         + b'\r\n'
   1045                 self.send(chunk)

TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

I deleted most of the result code because otherwise it wouldn't let me post the question. Let me know if you need more context and I will try to post the remaining part.

Maybe my python version is too updated (python 3). Any guesses?

Comment: which line is throwing the error? Post the *full stack trace*

Comment: sorry @juanpa.arrivillaga, this is the line showing the error **response, content=http.request(ENDPOINT, method="POST", body=content)** and this is the sull stack trace